# how to replace codeigniter urls with htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

i want to replace codeigniter urls with my own urls, i think .htaccess will help me to get desire urls, please check our ci urls, and suggest htaccess code... in single quotations, we are passing values, in codeigniter urls, 'page' & 'category' represent controller.

**For Pages:**

```
codeigniter URL: http://domain.com/page/'category-name'/'page-title'/

I want: http://domain.com/category-name/page-title.html
```

**For Category:**

```
Codeigniter URL: http://domain.com/category/'category-name'/

I want: http://domain.com/category-name/
```

**AND**

```
Codeigniter URL: http://domain.com/category/'category-name'/'index'/

I want: http://domain.com/category-name/index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use htaccess for that. Please read about routing setup in Codeigniter, this will make your app server software independent http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/routing.html

Comment: You don't need a .htaccess configuration, you just need to configure your routes. We can't help you without knowing your controllers structure, etc.